# How to make one column in an HTML table shrink-to-fit?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, html-table

I have a website that is using Bootstrap 4.5 framework. I am trying to create a table where the first column to auto fit its content. For example, if the content needs 100px, then the with of the first column will be 100px. and the rest of the columns will take up the rest of the space.

I tried creating the HTML table with the `col-auto` class on the first column but that did not work.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-striped">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="col-auto">First Column</td>
      <td>Second Column</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I make the first column to fit the content size.

Answer (score 0):

With bootstrap you can use the `col-X` classes to reset size within 12th fraction of table's width.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-striped">

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="col-2">First Column</td>
      <td class="col-10">Second Column</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

or

<table class="table table-striped">

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td >First Column</td>
      <td class="col">Second Column</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: In my case, I can't really do that. The table can have more than 12 columns. I just want to make the first column fit the content. My first column will always be small in my case. I tried using `col-auto` but it does not seems to have any affect.

Answer (score 0):

```
.table td {
  width: fit-content;
}
```